# efficient way to check for changes in a "calculation" class

Tags: c#, .net, string, memory, decimal

I have the following "calculation" class.

```
public class Foo
{

    private int? _sum = 0;

    public int Sum
    {
        get
        {
            if (_sum == null)
                _sum = 1 + 1; //simple code to show "some" calculation happens...

            return _sum.GetValueOrDefault();
        }
    }

}
```

In this example there is only 1 Field/Member but in my real class there are around 50 Members, that all look similar just with different value calculations.

In the class I also have a Recalc method.

This Recalc method does 4 things

1. Save the old values
2. set all fields to null
3. calls the getter of every member
4. Checks if the old values differ from the newvalues and does related stuff

I am not sure whats the best way to store the old values and check for changes with the new values.

My current implementation is this:

```
public string GetValuesKey()
{
    //again this method only handles the 1 Member and not all 50 in real app its string.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}|...{49}|{50}|", ....);
    return string.Format("{0}|", this.Sum);
}

public void Recalc()
{
    var oldValues = GetValuesKey();

    //set all fields to null
    //call the getters

    var newValues = GetValuesKey();
    if (oldValues != newValues)
    {
        //something changed...
    }
}
```

But with this code there is a memory/performance issue since I am doing boxing with the struct (decimal) writing to a reference type (string).

I kind of want to prevent doing 50 additional fields (something like _oldSum) for all the members.
I just need to check if any member has changed during the Recalc procedure.

Just in Case, I cannot do the following code.

```
public void Recalc()
{
    var changes = false;

    var oldValue = this.Sum;
    _sum = null;
    var newValue = this.Sum;
    if (oldValue != newValue)
        changes = true;

    //check next member
    oldValue = this.Sum2;
    _sum2 = null;
    newValue = this.Sum2;
    if (oldValue != newValue)
        changes = true;

    //check next member and so on...
}
```

Since I need to set all fields to null first and only AFTER all of them have been set to null I can execute the getters, since the members are dependant on each other for exmple if the Sum Member would aggregate two other members and they havent been set to null first they would still have old values.

So I need a way to store something that represents all values before setting the fields null and after calling the getter of the members a way to check for changes.

Any help is welcome.

**Edit:**

Here is the code, I wrote to test performance/memory:
http://pastebin.com/3WiNJHyS

Comment: Check this project I published some months ago: http://matiasfidemraizer.com/trackerdog

Comment: So using reflection is not an option for you? If not - why?

Comment: @Evk this class gets created 736.200 (in a rather big case - normally its like 1000-10000) times where each class has 50 members, reflection isn't an option since these numbers just make it to slow, I started it with reflection didn't create a dictionary like MK87 did but I had a list with a struct storing property name/value of the "oldvalues". I also hoped there is some calculation I could use to check for changes, something like Value1 + Value2 - (Value 3 + Value4) / Value5 (simplified)... if the sum of this equation changes during the recalc atleast one member had a change.

Comment: You can overcome reflection costs in different ways, for example compiled expression trees. If that is fine for you I can show how to do that in your case.

Comment: @Evk yes, pls do so.

Comment: Well I have some doubts still, because you want to even avoid boxing\unboxing and even fast reflection won't avoid this. Maybe you should just put all your values into array then compare arrays? Just like you do now but not put stuff in big string, and instead into array of decimals (or whatever type your fields are).

Comment: @Evk yeah they are all decimals, so you think that array initialization would be faster?

Comment: Well I hope you have some tests with which you can just verify that without guessing :)

Comment: @Evk gona give it a try, will report tomorrow.

Comment: @Evk had some spare time, array is looking good (didn't really expected this result) with 1.000.000 objects each containing the said 50 members. The array solution took 2148 ms and my current solution with string format takes 15872 ms, so its ~7 times faster. That's the code I use to perform the test http://pastebin.com/3WiNJHyS .

Comment: So you are satisfied or want to improve even more?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111454/discussion-between-evk-and-rand-random).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of combining all values in a string and have some pefomance hit on that string construction - put all values in array (of `decimal`), then set all fields to null, make your calculation and compare arrays of old and new values.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to write yourself all the 50 `_oldValue` fields, the only alternative is to use Reflection, that implies some boxing/unboxing, so performance will not be the best possible.

Anyway, in the following implementation I assume that in the `Foo` class the members that are involved in the calculation are all and the only ones that are properties of type `decimal?`.
Otherwise, we need a more complicated solution, with `BindingFlags`, and/or `Attribute` on every field/property involved, and so on.

```
public void Recalc()
{
    var propertyInfos = GetType()
        .GetProperties()
        .Where(pInfo => pInfo.PropertyType.IsValueType);

    var fieldInfos = GetType()
        .GetFields()
        .Where(fInfo => fInfo.FieldType.IsValueType);

    //create a dictionary with all the old values
    //obtained from the backing fields.
    var oldValueDictionary = fieldInfos.ToDictionary(
        fInfo => fInfo.Name,
        fInfo => (decimal?)fInfo.GetValue(this));

    //set all properties to null
    foreach (var pInfo in propertyInfos)
        pInfo.SetValue(this, null);

    //call all the getters to calculate the new values
    foreach (var pInfo in propertyInfos)
        pInfo.GetValue(this);

    //compare new field values with the old ones stored in the dictionary;
    //if only one different is found, the if is entered.
    if (fieldInfos.Any(fInfo =>
        (decimal?)fInfo.GetValue(this) != oldValueDictionary[fInfo.Name]))
    {
        //do stuffs
    }
}
```

As a final note, your class configuration is very strange. Are you sure that setting all the calculations in the getters is the best choice? Maybe you should re-think about you design. One task is to retrieve a property value (a getter), another task is to calculate something (starting from some value stored in the backing fields)...